# How do I find a word from my array, using the word boundaires, in a string?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, regex

I'm using Python 3.9.  I want to determine if a word from an array is in another string. I have

```
words = ['i', 'we', 'my', 'our', 'mine']
```

so this

```
title1 = "My mind"
```

should contain at least one word (the word "my"), but when I tried to write a regex it failed ...

```
>>> result = any(re.search(r'\b' + word + '\b',title1.lower()).group(0) for word in words)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: `'\b'` is a backspace char, you need `r'\b'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to check if *at least* a word is part of the sentence.

```
>>> any(re.search(rf"\b{word}\b", title1, re.IGNORECASE) for word in words)
True
```